# Mapping an array returns the commas

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code tries to find the value in the array for a given period, and I have no idea why the commas are included...

The correct array item is found and I'd like to know where my mistake is.

**How can I get just the value, without using replace/split etc.?**

I've tried using filter, but that one returns `2017-4,1287,12`, also weird.

```
console.log(period); // "2017-4"

console.log(data);

/* 
[ [ '2015-1', 280, 1 ],
  [ '2015-2', 21815, 2 ],
  [ '2015-3', 27892, 3 ],
  [ '2015-4', 49387, 4 ],
  [ '2016-1', 29997, 5 ],
  [ '2016-2', 31905, 6 ],
  [ '2016-3', 37341, 7 ],
  [ '2016-4', 30101, 8 ],
  [ '2017-1', 37439, 9 ],
  [ '2017-2', 31757, 10 ],
  [ '2017-3', 943, 11 ],
  [ '2017-4', 1287, 12 ],
  [ '2018-1', 17462, 13 ],
  [ '2018-2', 22617, 14 ],
  [ '2018-3', 27882, 15 ] ]
*/

let actual = data.map(item => {
    if (item[0] == period) return item[1];
});

console.log(actual); // ,,,,,,,,,,,1287,,,
```

Comment: Your code is creating an array based on `data` and since your `map()` function returns nothing / `undefined`, that's what you get in the array. You also seem to output `actual.toString()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for getting just a single item of an array.

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new array with either undefined or if `period` match, the wanted value.

```js
var period = "2017-4",
    data = [['2015-1', 280, 1], ['2015-2', 21815, 2], ['2015-3', 27892, 3], ['2015-4', 49387, 4], ['2016-1', 29997, 5], ['2016-2', 31905, 6], ['2016-3', 37341, 7], ['2016-4', 30101, 8], ['2017-1', 37439, 9], ['2017-2', 31757, 10], ['2017-3', 943, 11], ['2017-4', 1287, 12], ['2018-1', 17462, 13], ['2018-2', 22617, 14], ['2018-3', 27882, 15]],
    actual = data.find(([p]) => p === period)[1];

console.log(actual);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the commas because `.map` always returns an array the same length as the original - your function doesn't `return` anything when `item[0]` is not equal to `period`, and therefore returns `undefined`. (Although I am not sure why the console is not showing those explicit `undefined` values.)

If you want to only keep the values with the right date, you should use `.filter` instead of `.map`. (Actually `.filter` to reduce to just the desired results, then `.map` on the result to get the 2nd entry.)